# Unable to parse underneath double string with Object Mapper

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire, objectmapper

I have a model which have these two fields

```
var latitude: String?
var longitude: String?
```

I'm trying to parse the model. Everything is parsed correctly but only these two fields are never parsed.

Here's the complete model

```
import ObjectMapper
class BarberLoginModel: Mappable {
var id: Int?
var barberShopId: Int = 0
var firstName = ""
var lastName = ""
var mobileNo = ""
var userName = ""
var email = ""
var imgPath = ""
var shopName = ""
var address = ""
var street = ""
var area = ""
var emirates = ""
var latitude: String?
var longitude: String?
var Services: [ServiceModel]?
var Stylist: StylistArrayModel?
var Availability: [AvailabilityModel]?
var Facilities: [FacilitiesModel]?

required init?(map: Map) {

}

func mapping(map: Map) {
    id <- map["id"]
    barberShopId <- map["barberShopId"]
    firstName <- map["firstName"]
    lastName <- map["lastName"]
    mobileNo <- map["mobileNo"]
    userName <- map["userName"]
    email <- map["email"]
    imgPath <- map["imgPath"]
    shopName <- map["shopName"]
    address <- map["address"]
    street <- map["street"]
    area <- map["area"]
    emirates <- map["emirates"]
    latitude <- map["latitude"]
    longitude <- map["longitude"]
    Services <- map["Services"]
    Stylist <- map["Stylist"]
    Availability <- map["Availability"]
    Facilities <- map["Facilities"]
}
}
```

**Note:** When I change data type to Double? It works but it adds extra digits because of double.

[image: Left side is my parsed model and right side is raw view of data came from server]

**Link to json:** http://shaveme.stagingserver-me.com/api/ShopUserMaster?ln=en&t=1F10D5778C66A751766E8532EEAA0E1B&uid=21

Comment: What does your source data (Json?) look like?

Comment: @ptoinson Look at the right side of the image. That's source data

Comment: @NoorAli You should post your JSON instead of an Image

Comment: @UmairAfzal Json is so large there is so much irrelevant. Anywhoo Here's the link to json:
http://shaveme.stagingserver-me.com/api/ShopUserMaster?ln=en&t=1F10D5778C66A751766E8532EEAA0E1B&uid=21

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is pretty hard to debug without having access to the actual data. I put together a little test below. If you run it, you will know that the second XCTAssertEqual, in each test, fails because the original JSON data does not have quotes around the value 26.432. My guess is that you data is a number and not a string and therefore will not be unmarshalled properly.

```
import XCTest
import ObjectMapper

class Test : Mappable {
    var latitude: String?
    var longitude: String?

    required init?(map: Map) {

    }

    func mapping(map: Map) {
        latitude <- map["latitude"]
        longitude <- map["longitude"]
    }
}

class ObjectMapper_RndTests: XCTestCase {

    override func setUp() {
        super.setUp()
    }

    override func tearDown() {
        super.tearDown()
    }

    func testExample() {
        let json = "{\"longitude\": 26.432, \"latitude\":\"82.123\"}"
        let test = Test(JSONString: json);

        guard let t = test else {
            return
        }

        XCTAssertEqual(t.latitude, "82.123")
        XCTAssertEqual(t.longitude, "26.432")
    }

    func testExampleTwo() {
        let json = [ "longitude": 26.432, "latitude": "82.123" ] as [String : Any]
        let test = Test(JSON: json);

        guard let t = test else {
            return
        }

        XCTAssertEqual(t.latitude, "82.123")
        XCTAssertEqual(t.longitude, "26.432")
    }
}
```

The Solution, if you cannot change your data source to a String, is to use a transform. There is more info on the ObjectMapper site https://github.com/Hearst-DD/ObjectMapper. It looks like this.

```
class Test : Mappable {
    var latitude: String?
    var longitude: String?

    required init?(map: Map) {

    }

    func mapping(map: Map) {

        let transform = TransformOf<String, Double>(fromJSON: { (value: Double?) -> String? in

            if let v = value {
                NSLog("from json value: " + String(v))
                return String(v)
            }
            NSLog("from json value: null")
            return nil
        }, toJSON: { (value: String?) -> Double? in
            // transform value from Double? to String?
            if let value = value {
                return Double(value)
            }
            return nil
        })

        latitude <- (map["latitude"], transform)
        longitude <- (map["longitude"], transform)
    }
}
```

Comment: Confusion was double quotes. Because I did not have access to server and when I printed the response from server it showed me double quotes around the data. So I though it could be string.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, u could do it manually. Cleaner and shorter codes

```
class BarberLoginModel: Mappable {

    var latitude: Double?
    var longitude: Double?

    required convenience init?(map: Map) {
        self.init()
    }

    func mapping(map: Map) {
        var latitude: String?
        var  longitude: String?
        latitude <- map["latitude"]
        longitude <- map["longitude"]

        if let latitude = latitude {
            self.latitude = Double(string: latitude)
        }
        if let longitude = longitude {
            self.longitude = Double(string: longitude)
        }
    }
}
```